# Javascript: Removing all elements within a div except for one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good evening!

I have a HTML document which contains a lot of  elements in a container div that represent movie titles. I have an input box in which the user can search for a movie title and if there is a match, I want to empty the container div that contains the  elements completely, EXCEPT for the matched movie title. So far I have been trying to do it like this:

```
function Search() {
    var userinput = document.getElementById("userinput").value.toLowerCase();
    if (!userinput.replace(/\s+/g, '')) {
        alert('You havent entered any search words.');
        return;
    }

    userinput = userinput.toLowerCase();
    var list = document.getElementsByTagName("h3");
    var i = list.length,
        html, flag = false,
        matches = [];

    while (i--) {
        var html = list[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase();
        if (-1 < html.indexOf(userinput)) {
            flag = true;
            matches.push(list[i]);
            list[i].className = "matched";
        }
    }

    if (!flag) //geen match
    {
        if (-1 !== html.indexOf(userinput))
            alert('No match found !');
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
            matches[i].style.backgroundColor = "#ff6d6d";
            $("#overzicht_list").children().filter(function() {
                return $(this).text().indexOf(matches[i]) < -1;
            }).remove();
        }
    }
```

HTML Example of Full movie:

```
<div class="overzicht-wrap" id="overzicht-wrap">
            <div class="container module">
                <ul class="overzicht_list" id="overzicht_list">
                    <li class="overzicht_list_item">
                        <div class="item_info">
                            <img class="item_cover" src="images/covers/as_above_so_below.jpg" alt="As Above, So Below cover">

                            <a href="#" class="button-inactive">Draait niet meer</a>
                        </div>
                        <!-- end item_info -->

                        <div class="item_content">
                        <h3>as above, so below</h3>
                            <p>
                                Onder de straten van Parijs liggen kilometers aan gangenstelsels, de eeuwige thuishaven van talloze zielen. Wanneer een team van ontdekkingsreizigers het doolhof van botten verkent, ontdekt men het duistere geheim dat binnen deze stad van de doden ligt verscholen...
                            </p>

                            <a href="details/as_above_so_below.html">Lees meer</a>   <a onclick="SetFavorites()"><i class="fi-star" id="star"></i></a>

                            <ul class="ratings">
                                <li><img src="images/ratings/16.png" alt="16"></li>
                                <li><img src="images/ratings/angst.png" alt="16"></li>
                                <li><img src="images/ratings/geweld.png" alt="16"></li>
                                <li><img src="images/ratings/grof_taalgebruik.png" alt="16"></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <!-- end overzicht_list_item. Do note that the divs above are closed elsewhere -->
```

As you can see, I start off by doing some simple input validation to see if the user has actually entered anything. Them, I declare a bunch of variables for later use.

Afterwards, I loop through the List Var that contains all of the  elements. If there is a match with the userinput, the variable flag gets set to true and the name of the matched  element gets pushed into the matches[] array.

Then, if the flag variable is set to true I want the script to remove every element in the overzicht_container (the word "overzicht" means "overview" in dutch, sorry about that) EXCEPT for the matched  element.

This last bit is what is troubling me. I cannot seem to get it to work: I tried to filter the Remove() event as you can see, but nothing gets removed.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: And your relevant HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And one more version. Note: I didn't remove elements but hid them. It allows to show relevant results even after typing in other word in `<input>`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6n7pqod2/1/).

HTML:

```
<input type="text" title="Zoekbalk" id="userinput" placeholder="Typ hier om te zoeken" class="input_box" />
<ul class="overzicht_list" id="overzicht_list">
    <h3>first</h3>
    <h3>second</h3>
    <h3>third</h3>
    <h3>four</h3>
    <h3>five</h3>
    <h3>six</h3>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.matched
{
    background-color: #ff6d6d
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#userinput').change(function()
    {
        var userinput = this.value.toLowerCase();
        var allElements = $('#overzicht_list h3');
        if (!userinput.replace(/\s+/g, ''))
        {
            alert("You haven't entered any search words.");
            allElements.removeClass("matched").show();
            return;
        }
        allElements.removeClass("matched").hide();
        allElements.filter(function()
        {
            var text = this.textContent.toLowerCase();
            return (text.indexOf(userinput) > -1);
        }).addClass("matched").show();
    });
});
```

**Update**. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6n7pqod2/3/) for hiding all children (not only `<h3>`) and showing `<li>` and `<div>`, in which `<h3>` are wrapped.

Comment: Looks good, but the thing is that I need to remove/hide every single element within the overzicht_list, not just <h3> elements. Sorry if I was unclear in my description, but that is really my goal: To remove/hide every single HTML element except for the matched <h3>. I'm not really sure if your code does this already, can you tell me this?

Comment: @user3521018 is [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6n7pqod2/2/) what you are talking about? Hiding all list children except matched `<h3>`.

Comment: yes this is exactly what I am talking about! Youre fiddle works fine, but I can't seem to get the code working in my own HTML: I get no mtaches whatsoever. I think this is due to my own HTML, I'll post it completely in my question above. Btw, thanks a lot for helping me out so far man :)

Comment: @user3521018 you're welcome. This is because `<h3>` is wrapped with `<div>` and ``<li>``, which are hidden. Take a look at [one more updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6n7pqod2/3/) to see how it can be done by using additional `.parents().show()`

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you very much for your time, you really helped me out here Regent :)

Answer (score 1):

You're doing this the hard way. Empty all the children and put the one you want back in:

```
var matched = match; //the matched node if found
var node = document.getElementById("foo");
while (node.firstChild) {
    node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
}
node.appendChild(matched);
```

Comment: var node would be in my case, document.getelementbyid("overzicht_list"); ?

Comment: That is correct. It is easier to dump (or hide) them all then replace (or show) the one you want.